# Django не работает {% csrf_token %}

Tags: python, django, csrf

Приветствую.
Сломал уже голову. Никак не хочет работать `{% csrf_token %}`.
Использую Django v2.0.1, Добавил  `'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'` в самое начало `MIDDLEWARE`. В шаблоне рисую так:

```
<form class="..." action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
```

Рендерю шаблон так:
    return render_to_response(
        'index.html',
        { },
    )
И еще так пробовал:
    return render(
        request,
        'index.html',
        {}
    )
Никаких декораторов на вьюхах нет. На нажатие кнопки button type="submit" есть скрипт, который отправляет ajax-запрос. И вот при нажатии получаю 403

> (Ошибка проверки CSRF. Запрос отклонён.  CSRF cookie not set. )

Как бы не пытался найти решение, а скрытое поле с csrf-ключом так и не создается в форме.

Может кто знает в чем может быть дело и подскажет ?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72133/discussion-on-question-by-genome-django---csrf-token).

Answer (score 1):

Не хватает контекста, обычно данная ошибка возникает из-за старых примеров и учебников. Рекомендуемая сокращенная функция для вывода шаблона это **render()**.

Если используется HttpResponse, то нужно передавать [context](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial03/).

Он нужен для того, чтобы корректно отрабатывали встроенные теги, т.к. иначе о них ничего не известно.

Столько функций для рендера нужно для разных вариантов разработки и оптимизации. Если шаблон не нужен, то не нужно и вызывать обработку шаблонизатора, экономия на ресурсах, улучшение производительности.

Так же много устаревших функций и примеров, поэтому всегда используйте документацию для той версии с которой работаете, иначе потратите несколько дней из-за того что теперь не нужны кавычки или порядок изменился.